# Elastic search query to return either or values

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch. I am trying to write elasticsearch query to return either or values. Return results if statusfield == status1 or  statusfield == status2. Below query is giving error

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
         
        {       
        "match": {
            "status": ["status1","status2"]
        }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": []
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `terms` which accepts an array of values instead of `match` which doesn't

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
         
        {       
        "terms": {                              <--- change this
            "status": ["status1","status2"]
        }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": []
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is working. Thank you